# WinRT XAML Toolkit: can we use it in windows phone 8.1 and windows 8.1 universal app

Tags: winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I am developing a charting app and want to use WinRT XAML Toolkit data visualization in both (Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1) of the projects in my universal app.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortuatly WinRT XAML Toolkit (https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/) only work for Windows Runtime XAML applications.
My recommendation is that you create 2 pages (sadly) or usercontrols and use winrtxamltoolkit for your windows 8.1 app and another data visualization toolkit like telerik maybe for the windows phone 8.1 (http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/chart.aspx).

With a bit of luck you will be able to bind the same property on both controls, best of luck!

Comment: Isn't Windows Phone 8.1 that is part of the Universal app also a Windows Runtime XAML application?

Comment: Yes but in a Universal app you have 3 "solutions", you have an app.Windows (Windows 8.1), app.WindowsPhone (Windows Phone 8.1) and app.shared where you can share the code for both plateforms

Comment: I understand, since Windows Phone 8.1 is also Windows Runtime XAML application, one should ideally be able to add the WinRT Xaml Toolkit from Nuget to that project. I think it is still under its way by looking at codeplex.

Comment: we are able to use winrt xaml toolkit data visualization (for making chart). can use source code from [link](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ReadMe.txt) or we can use nuget ready to use lib for winrtxaml data viz.

Answer (score 1):

Update for anyone finding this ticket, WinRTXamlToolkit is available now for windows phone 8.1 called:

WinRTXamlToolkit.WindowsPhone available via NuGet. I mention this as had almost decided not to use the package and it's solved a chunk of my problems.